# WebAssembly Blazor to Azure Linux Deploy: "Your web app is running and waiting for your content"

Tags: linux, azure, azure-web-app-service, blazor, azure-virtual-machine

I've deployed an app to Azure, but when I go to mysite.azurewebsites.net, I'm told "Your web app is running and waiting for your content"

It's a WebAssembly Blazor app on a B1 tier with a Linux box deployed via Github Actions. It *had* been running great on a Windows App Service, but I deleted and recreated with Linux to save some money.

The deployment appears to have been successful:

````
    "id": [A PROPER GUID],
    "status": 4,
    "status_text": "",
    "author_email": "N/A",
    "author": "N/A",
    "deployer": "GITHUB_ZIP_DEPLOY",
    "message": "{\"type\":\"deployment\",\"sha\":\[A PROPER SHA],\"repoName\":\"emersonp/MyApp\",\"slotName\":\"Production\",\"commitMessage\":\"Roadmap!\"}",
    "progress": "",
    "received_time": "2022-10-14T18:41:31.9234067Z",
    "start_time": "2022-10-14T18:41:33.2864838Z",
    "end_time": "2022-10-14T18:41:42.5335373Z",
    "last_success_end_time": "2022-10-14T18:41:42.5335373Z",
    "complete": true,
    "active": true,
    "is_temp": false,
    "is_readonly": true,
    "url": "https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/[GUID]",
    "log_url": "https://myapp.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/[GUID]/log",
    "site_name": "myapp",
    "build_summary": {
      "errors": [],
      "warnings": []
    }```

[![Deployment Center shows fine][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lws4B.png
````

Comment: Is this a Linux App Service? Maybe there is some settings missing, like the startup dll.
Perhaps try to publish from Visual Studio and see if that works, that's what I'm doing and it has been working well.

Comment: You can check the actual content from kudu (or with ftp). What is in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From our discussion thread on [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1048826/index.html), as JasonPan-MSFT mentioned:

> "According to [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#azure-app-service), deploying Blazor
> WebAssembly projects on Azure Web App Linux is currently not
> supported."

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I missed that. That's unfortunate. Digital Ocean it is.

Comment: That is really sad, Blazor WASM on .Net 5 deployed just fine to Linux.